# Nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I've got the following `MapOverlay`. The following line is throwing a NullPointer but I don't understand why :S `mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);` could anyone help me out?

```
    public class Mapview extends MapActivity {
GeoPoint p;
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
 return false;
}
public int icount = 0;
MapController mapController;
MyPositionOverlay positionOverlay;
private LocationData tweets;
public int start = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);



MapView myMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);

myMapView.setSatellite(true);
myMapView.setStreetView(true);
myMapView.displayZoomControls(false);
mapController = myMapView.getController();

mapController.setZoom(17);
myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

//Adding points here


//---Add a location marker---
MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

myMapView.invalidate();

// Add the MyPositionOverlay
positionOverlay = new MyPositionOverlay();
List<Overlay> overlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
overlays.add(positionOverlay);


LocationManager locationManager;
String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
criteria.setSpeedRequired(false);
criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10, locationListener);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
updateWithNewLocation(location);

}


private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
  updateWithNewLocation(null);
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                            Bundle extras){ }
 };

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
String latLongString ="";
TextView myLocationText;
myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
String addressString = "No address found";

if (location != null) {
     // Update my location marker
    positionOverlay.setLocation(location);

  // Update the map location.
  Double geoLat = location.getLatitude()*1E6;
  Double geoLng = location.getLongitude()*1E6;
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(), 
                                geoLng.intValue());

  mapController.animateTo(point);

  double lat = location.getLatitude();
  double lng = location.getLongitude();
  latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;
  Global.lat = lat;
  Global.lng = lng;
  double latitude = location.getLatitude();
  double longitude = location.getLongitude();

  Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
  try {
    List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, 
                                                 longitude, 1);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
      Address address = addresses.get(0);

      for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
    }
    addressString = sb.toString();
  } catch (IOException e) {}
} else {
  latLongString = "No location found";
}
}

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
  @Override
  public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
  boolean shadow, long when) 
  {
      super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

      //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
      Point screenPts = new Point();
      mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

      //---add the marker---
      Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
          getResources(), R.drawable.marker);            
      canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
      return true;
 } 

 }
}
```

Comment: I can't see, where `p` comes from...

Comment: It's declared as `Geopoint p;` earlier. I've added more code to make this clearer sorry.

Comment: thank you. I cant the the error, have you found out which object is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a declaration of GeoPoint `p` but no expression where `p` is actually initialized. So passing `null` to the `toPixels()` method could be a cause for the NPE.

Try this code instead to check, if the NPE is gone:

```
  //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
  if (p == null) return false;
  Point screenPts = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, null);
```

<sub>(I don't like 'out' parameters in Java, toPixels will create the point object for you
and return it)</sub>

Comment: Your code helped me debug it further. I was able to solve the remainder. Basically I wasn't giving p a point :) thanks man.

Comment: That's what I expected. The only other reasons for NPE at this place would have been a `null` instead of a MapView or a `null` instead of a projection and one of these case would have been a serious bug on android ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that the public attribute GeoPoint p is never referenced 
thus pointint on null.
Maybe you wanted to define p in this line:

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(geoLat.intValue(), 
                                geoLng.intValue());

You should find the corredt place to assign p, then the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain a reference to the `myMapView` that you will use later. The way to do this is to declare it as a property, using the `strong` attribute.